# How to disable AdMob ads test mode?

Tags: admob, ads

How do I disable my admob ad test mode to show the real ad?  I couldn't find a button to disable the test mode, and besides, I haven't published my app yet

I checked the app setting section, but there was nothing there to disable the test mode

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are not using [Demo Ad units](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#demo_ad_units) and you are using your own Ad units
2. Make sure to remove [Added Test Devices](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#enable_test_devices) from code